# What should be used in sentence 'to sleep' or 'to be slept'

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Following are two sentences. Which one is correct?
-- She sang her baby **to sleep**
-- She sang her baby **to be slept**
Please answer this.

Comment: I still don't even know if "slept" is a word in English, and I'm not sure anyone does!

Comment: "slept" is certainly a word in British English, e.g. "I slept till noon".

Comment: There are very few scenarios where the words "be slept" would be idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

> She sang her baby **to sleep**.

The verb *to sleep* is intransitive, i.e. it doesn't take a direct object (you can't *sleep someone/something*). As such, it can't be put into the passive voice.

EDIT:

On second thoughts, *sleep* shouldn't be considered a verb here at all, but a noun. The sentence structure is essentially the same as in *He bored his students to death,* and might be better understood as a simplified version of:

> She sang her baby **into a state of sleep**.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the OP has confused the simple past and past participle of the irregular verb *sleep* (slept) with its adjectival form *asleep*. However, to *[sing someone to sleep](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sing-someone-to-sleep)* is a fixed **phrase**, and only the main verb, *sing*, is inflected.

> ### [sing someone to sleep](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/sing_someone_to_sleep)
>
> PHRASE
>
> Cause someone to fall asleep by singing gently to them.
>
> ### [asleep](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/asleep)
>
> adjective, predicative: In a state of sleep.
>
> - ‘she had been asleep for over three hours’
> - ‘a man lay asleep’
> - ‘he soon fell asleep’
>
> <sup>*Oxford Living Dictionaries*</sup>

Thus the OP's sentences should read

- She ***sings*** her baby to sleep every night (Simple Present)
- She ***sang*** her baby to sleep (Simple Past)
- She *sings* until her baby ***falls*** asleep (Simple Present)
- She *sang* until the baby ***fell*** asleep (Simple Past)
- She *sang* until her baby ***had fallen*** asleep. (Past Perfect)